# What is data-toggle="modal" used for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button code which someone created it. Here are the button code:

```
<button class="demo btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#long"  onClick="javascript:add();"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add Employee</button>
```

I've edit the function related to the button (send the new data from the button, and call it in the function), but nothing happened. Then I tried to delete `data-toggle="modal"`, the pop up didn't show. So, I wonder, what is `data-toggle="modal"` use for?

I thought here are the link to modal:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

Can anyone explain me about `data-toggle="modal"`? Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

From the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

```
<!--Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set data-toggle="modal" on a 
controller element, like a button, along with a data-target="#foo" or href="#foo" 
to target a specific modal to toggle.-->

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

Comment: How do I close the Modal from JavaScript after this opened up?

Comment: @ppumkin To dismiss a modal once it is opened - without using javascript you can use:

    `<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>`